# WSGI: Django App is not getting the required site-packages

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

Unfortuanetely I am stuck with my Website returning a 500 error.

The apache log is not really specific, and so I do not really know what to do. Before some apt-get upgrades everything worked fine.

I do think this might be a permission error. How do I have to set the permissions working with WSGI?

Or do you know why this problem could be occuring for another reason?

apache conf:

```
...
WSGIDaemonProcess aegee-stuttgart.org  python-path=/home/sysadmin/public_html/aegee-stuttgart.org:/home/sysadmin/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.7
    WSGIProcessGroup aegee-stuttgart.org
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sysadmin/public_html/aegee-stuttgart.org/aegee/wsgi.py
...
```

wsgi.py:

```
...
import os, sys

# add the aegee project path into the sys.path
sys.path.append('/home/sysadmin/public_html/aegee-stuttgart.org/aegee')

# add the virtualenv site-packages path to the sys.path
sys.path.append('/home/sysadmin/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
import django
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
...
```

error.log:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=23202): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/sysadmin/p$
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/sysadmin/public_html/aegee-stuttgart.org/aegee/wsgi.py", line 31, i$
   return super(WSGIEnvironment, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189,$
   response = self.get_response(request)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218,$
   response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 264,$
   if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 395, $
   self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
   __import__(name)
 File "/home/sysadmin/public_html/aegee-stuttgart.org/aegee/urls.py", line 8, in$
   from .userprofile.views import AccountPersonalInfoView
 File "/home/sysadmin/public_html/aegee-stuttgart.org/aegee/userprofile/views.py$
   from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
ImportError: No module named mixins
```

Comment: It says in the last line: `from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin -- ImportError: No module named mixins`. Are you running Django 1.9.x or later?

Comment: I am running django 1.9.9 in the virtualenv, but apparently wsgi does not recognise that... I have no clue on how to fix this

Comment: It seems that an earlier version of Django module is being used, because it appears earlier in `sys.path`.  Perhaps in `wsgi.py` you could try inserting the virtualenv site-packages directory as the _first_ entry, instead of appending it to the end?

Comment: What did the `apt-get` upgrade? Also, can you still start the app via `./manage.py runserver`? I would guess an Apache config problem, because when `wsgi.py` starts up, that should already be using the Virtualenv. But it is using the system installation at `/usr/lib/python2.7/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess aegee-stuttgart.org python-home=/home/sysadmin/.virtualenvs/django python-path=/home/sysadmin/public_html/aegee-stuttgart.org
```

not what you had. It is possible to use `python-path` to refer to a virtual environment, but you were using the wrong directory. Use `python-home` instead and set it to same directory as `sys.prefix` gives for the virtual environment.

Because you were using wrong directory, it was picking up Django from main Python installation and not the virtual environment.